# Cannot handle FaultException by reflection invoking

Tags: targetinvocationexception

I am preparing a client for WCF service.
I provoked an fault exception in some method on a service site. I mean:

```
throw new FaultException<sth>(new sth())
```

When I catch this exception in WPF appliction:

```
catch (FaultException<sth> ex)
{
     // something
}
```

everything works very clearly.

My point is, that I made a reflection on the service interface.

```
var type = typeof (someServiceInterface);
type.GetMethods();
```

and I want to catch the FaultException, when I call the method service in this way

```
try
{
    var singleMethod = //do sth to get method
    var result = singleMethod.Invoke(proxy, parameters);
    return result;
}
catch (FaultException<sth> ex)
{
    //1
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //2
}
```

But I catch an Exception in second catch, not in the first. The type of this Exception is "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException". I am confused and I wonder what cause such kind of problem.